# Did tag score stop working?

Tags: bug, tags

Usually tag score gets updated daily.

I noticed that for the last 3 days or so, although I got upvoted on certain tags, the tag score has not changed. Is this a bug?

Comment: I have seen the same problem. I looked at the API at one point and saw I had over 400 score in the python tag (and had for at least 1-2 days). I didn't get the silver badge until over a whole week later, because it didn't update until then.

Comment: This is normal, it happens every now and then.

Comment: There is a long history of that script with its irratic behavior: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run